# JSON CRUD operations with LoDash and ParseDB

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, lodash

I'm using Javascript with Lodash and an Express/Parse back end.  Given a collection with 3 columns, two of which have unique strings and one of which that houses objects in the form of:

```
{
  "Array1": [
    {object},
    {object}
  ],
  "Array2": [
    {object},
    {object},
    {object}
  ],
  "GlobalID": "xxxxx"
}
```

Each of the {objects} houses a number of additional objects, some of which are nested along with an objectID.  Using the GlobalID and the objectID I'd like to delete a given object that is inside a chosen array. I've tried everything I can think of using a combination of Lodash and Parse.Query thus far. I think I've been able to successfully select the object at the column level using the GlobalID but I have not been able to reach into an array and select a targeted object for deletion with the objectID. How do you do this? I'm sure there is more than one way. I'll take whatever advice you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about lodash, but the question is answerable without it.

Say you have the GlobalID of the outer object and it's `myGlobalID`.  And say you know that you want to delete from "Array2", and say the id of the inner object you want to delete is `innerObjectId`.  Then...

...this looks up the outer object:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("OuterObject");
query.equalTo("GlobalID", myGlobalID)
query.first();   // assumes unique global id, otherwise use find()
```

... and since the question implies that the arrays are pointers to other objects, you need to create one suitable for removing:

```
var pointer = new InnerObject();
pointer.id = innerObjectId;
```

... now we're ready to remove:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("OuterObject");
query.equalTo("GlobalID", myGlobalID)
query.first().then(function(object) {
    var pointer = new InnerObject();
    pointer.id = innerObjectId;
    object.remove("Array2", pointer);
    return object.save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I lose you on the second portion.  var pointer = new InnerObject();? I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but  how do I define an InnerObject that looks like:

{
    "_account": "YzzrzBrO9OMKqeo",
    "_id": "600r0LrVvViXjqZoeaVz",
    "date": "2014-05-12",
    "pending": false,
    "score": {
      "master": 1,
      "detail": {
        "address": 1,
        "city": 1,
        "state": 1
      }
    },
    "category": [
      "Food and Drink",
      "Restaurants"
    ],
    "category_id": "13005000"
  },

Every time I try run the code InnerObject is undefined.

Comment: By the way, it seems as if one of the major issues is that i have to filter for 'hashedJSON'. Why should I have to do this? It seems rather arbitrary and it doesn't appear with this key in my actually data store.

Comment: The goal of the second part of the code is to build a pointer whose objectId (parse's id) matches the inner object that you wish to remove.  There's no need to create a complete object...only enough to match when remove() removes it.